# Pre-creating UICollectionView cells - layout issue

Tags: performance, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableView` with 6 rows. Each row contains a single `UICollectionView`. Each collection view contains a single section with 10-15 cells. One view controller is the datasource and delegate for both the table view and the collection view.

[image]

I would like to address some performance issues when scrolling the tableview. Whenever a new section comes into view, there is a small pause while the collection view is created and filled. Since I have a fixed number of cells (< 100) and they are *almost* static (they are initially loaded from a web API but the data will change only a couple of times a week), I would like to pre-build each of the collection view cells in advance. I would prefer the user waits an extra half-second on launch than encounters jerky scrolling.

To accomplish this, I have updated my `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to check a dictionary of cells I am maintaining. It looks for a key composited from the collection view index and the indexPath for the cell. If the key exists, the corresponding object is returned. If none is found, the cell is built and also added to the dictionary. This step effectively prevents cells from being un-loaded and recycled, at the expense of using more memory.

But on launch, I still need to run this once for each cell to pre-populate the dictionary. I iterate over each table view cell, find the collection view, and call

`[self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

This is almost enough. The cells are being created and stored in the dictionary, and when I scroll to a new collection view, I see that they are being pulled from the dictionary and are displayed. But all of the cells, and all of their contents, are shoved up in the top-left corner at {0,0}.

Some logging tells me that at the time the cells are created, the frame of the collection view is {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}. I assume this is why none of my layout is being applied?

How can I resolve this?

(Would also be interested in any general comments on my pre-loading implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by calling `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` on the `UITableViewCell` (**not** the collection view). A more thorough explanation is welcomed.